# Crash in SceneKit on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a crash on SceneKit reported by multiple users on Crashlytics. It happens on a lot of devices (iPhone SE, iPhone 12, iPhone 11 Pro Max...) on iOS 14. They seem to appear quite randomly.

The callstack only contains SceneKit calls.

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0068006b006a0099

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  SceneKit                       0x1dd1873a4 C3DAnimationManagerRemoveAnimationsForObject + 48
1  SceneKit                       0x1dd33604c C3DEntityRemoveAllAnimations + 44
2  SceneKit                       0x1dd335fe4 C3DEntityCFFinalize + 24
3  SceneKit                       0x1dd180488 _C3DMeshSourceCFFinalize + 112
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1a8952aac _CFRelease + 248
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1a88afd88 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 192
6  SceneKit                       0x1dd23df08 _C3DMeshCFFinalize + 84
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1a8952aac _CFRelease + 248
8  SceneKit                       0x1dd1c2a00 _C3DRendererElementFinalize + 96
9  SceneKit                       0x1dd3c2c70 __C3DRendererElementStoreDeallocateSpan + 164
10 SceneKit                       0x1dd3c2d88 C3DRendererElementStoreDeallocateSpanForNode + 64
11 SceneKit                       0x1dd2439dc C3DSceneNodeWillBeRemovedOrHidden + 48
12 SceneKit                       0x1dd239584 _C3DNodeWillRemoveFromScene + 36
13 SceneKit                       0x1dd168440 C3DRemoveSceneRef + 160
14 SceneKit                       0x1dd2394c8 _C3DNodeEnumerateSubEntities + 408
15 SceneKit                       0x1dd16849c C3DRemoveSceneRef + 252
16 SceneKit                       0x1dd2394c8 _C3DNodeEnumerateSubEntities + 408
17 SceneKit                       0x1dd16849c C3DRemoveSceneRef + 252
18 SceneKit                       0x1dd2394e0 _C3DNodeEnumerateSubEntities + 432
19 SceneKit                       0x1dd16849c C3DRemoveSceneRef + 252
20 SceneKit                       0x1dd2394e0 _C3DNodeEnumerateSubEntities + 432
21 SceneKit                       0x1dd16849c C3DRemoveSceneRef + 252
22 SceneKit                       0x1dd2449d4 _C3DSceneCFFinalize + 188
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1a8952aac _CFRelease + 248
24 SceneKit                       0x1dd374958 C3DTransactionFlush + 2112
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1a894fc74 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
26 CoreFoundation                 0x1a8949d98 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 572
27 CoreFoundation                 0x1a894a344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1052
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1a89499f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
29 GraphicsServices               0x1c001a734 GSEventRunModal + 164
30 UIKitCore                      0x1ab3c775c -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
31 UIKitCore                      0x1ab3ccfcc UIApplicationMain + 168
32 TagHeuerGolf                   0x100084cac main + 27 (main.swift:27)
33 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a8605cf8 start + 4
```

Does someone have the same crashes? If so, did you find a solution to fix it?

Comment: Can you reproduce this error? Does it happens always, iEx at device startup or totally randomly? (Real device / Simulator). Could it be a memory issue? Do you perform some synchronous actions on the Main Thread (like the Dispatch Queue?), what easely results into a deadlock?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I don't know exactly when it happens since I never noticed the crash myself, I just see it in our Crashlytics reports (so only on real devices). 
It might be memory issues but I have devices with 1.23 GB RAM left that crashed (and it happens on new devices with lot of memory).
I dont think there might be deadlocks but I'll look more into this.

Comment: @Djava7 is this problem specific to some or all iOS versions? The behavior of crashes seems different from a version to another one, at least from what I see on my side.

Comment: Mmm actually you made me realize that it was mostly on iOS 14.7.1 and 14.8.0. For example, on the last 30 days, we had 351 crashs on 14.7.1, 99 on 14.8.0, and it drops to 44 for all other iOS versions combined. I also noticed that there is none on iOS 15. 
That makes me wonder if the SceneKit team changed something that fixes those crashes in the version shipped with iOS 15.

Comment: Seems reasonable to assume iOS15 fixed some bug in iOS14 on SceneKit, but wait are you comparing apples with oranges? Is this the same number of users? Can you tell?